# jQuery function doesn't work on Safari

Tags: function, sorting, safari

I've one function for sort div by price ASC and DESC. But it **doesn't work on Safari**.
It's ok on Firefox/Chrome.

What's the reason?

The code (and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/jKJc3/) version):

```
  function sortByPrice(a,b){
      return $(a).find('.cicerone_price').text() > $(b).find('.cicerone_price').text();
  }

  function sortByPriceDesc(a,b){
     return $(a).find('.cicerone_price').text() < $(b).find('.cicerone_price').text();
  }

  function reorderEl(el){
      var container = $('#tabs');
      container.html('');
      el.each(function(){
          $(this).appendTo(container);
      });
  }
  $('#filter_price').change(function(){
      if ($("#filter_price option:selected").val()=='desc'){ 
          reorderEl($('.global_product').sort(sortByPriceDesc));
         } else if ($("#filter_price option:selected").val()=='asc'){ 
            reorderEl($('.global_product').sort(sortByPrice));
            }
  });
```

Comment: Safari does not seem to like your returning a boolean value from your comparison functions for sorting. Return -1/1 instead (and maybe 0 for elements with equal sort criterion).

Comment: do you have any issue for that ? i'm lost -_-

Comment: I updated your fiddle – works fine for me that way in Safari 5.1.7/Win7.

Comment: you can copy/paste the code ? I cant see on my fiddle link the update ?!
Thx a lot !

Comment: Sorry, I thought it updated, but seems it didn’t. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/3kcwW/1/

Comment: i found other problem, when you put one price width 230$, 21$ and 150$. Sorting is => 230$ => 21$ => 150$. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3kcwW/3/

Comment: Well, that happens when you lexically compare _strings_ instead of numbers. So you should put the price info into an element where you can read it from without the $ sign and then parse it into a number before comparing.

Comment: how i can do that ? i'm novice in jquery :(

Comment: Native JavaScript offers the methods `parseInt`/`parseFloat` to convert strings containing numerical data into real numbers.

Comment: ok, i check on google what is it. But i dont know how i can implemant on my jquery ?!

Comment: thx for the help CBroe, i found my error, my fiddle corrected : 
http://jsfiddle.net/3kcwW/8/

Comment: @artSx If you solved the problem, you should post the solution as an answer and then accept it. Then it will help future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has been solved, for the solution, i add parseFloat for decimal

solution is here : [fiddle correction](http://jsfiddle.net/3kcwW/8/)

```
function sortByPrice(a,b){
    return parseFloat($(a).find('.productPriceForSorting').text()) > parseFloat($(b).find('.productPriceForSorting').text()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```