# jquery sort function not working in safari and chrome

Tags: jquery, sorting

Hello i have a problem with a sort function.
I've already looked at this : [jQuery function doesn't work on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881098/jquery-function-doesnt-work-on-safari)
Using parsefloat does not resolved my problem. Can somebody help?

This script work perfectly in Firefox.

```
var totalProdblk,priceAsc,priceDesc;
totalProdblk = $('.prodblk');
priceAsc = $('#priceAsc');
priceDesc = $('#priceDesc');

// Price
priceAsc.click(function(){
    totalProdblk.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.getAttribute('data-price') > b.getAttribute('data-price')
    }).appendTo(totalProdblk.parent());
});

priceDesc.click(function(){
    totalProdblk.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.getAttribute('data-price') < b.getAttribute('data-price')
    }).appendTo(totalProdblk.parent());
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: There's some known issues on sorting without returning a value, i can't remember the exact specifics.
try 

    var upA = a.getAttribute('data-price');
    var upB = b.getAttribute('data-price');
    return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;

Comment: Thanks a lot briansol, you were right!